# How to remove the last field depends on other field value using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need one help. I need to delete some field which has added as per other input field value.Let me to explain my code.

```
<div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px;">No of questions : 
<input name="question" id="ques" class="form-control" placeholder="no of question" value="<?php if($_REQUEST['edit']) { echo $getcustomerobj->no_of_question; } else { echo $_REQUEST['no_of_question']; } ?>" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
<div id="err_msg_name" style="font-size:12px; color:#FF0000; text-align: center;"></div>
 </div>
<div style="width:24%; float:left; padding:10px;" id="container">questions : 
 <textarea class="form-control" name="questions0" id="questions" placeholder="Questions"  style="background:#FFFFFF;"  rows="2"><?php if($_REQUEST['edit']) { echo $getcustomerobj->questions; } else { echo $_REQUEST['questions']; } ?></textarea>
 </div>
<div style="float:left;margin-top:37px;">
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" onClick="addQuestionField();"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="minus" id="minus" value="-" onClick="deleteQuestionField();">
</div>
```

my javascript part is given below.

```
function addQuestionField(){
    var get =$("#ques").val();
    if(get==null || get==''){
        alert('Please add no of questions');
    }else{
        var counter = 0;
        if (counter > 0){
            return;
        }else{
             counter++;
             for(var i=1;i<get;i++){
                 $('#container').append(' <textarea class="form-control" name="questions'+ i +'" id="questions" placeholder="Questions"  style="background:#FFFFFF;"  rows="2"><?php if($_REQUEST['edit']) { echo $getcustomerobj->questions; } else { echo $_REQUEST['questions']; } ?></textarea>');
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Here suppose user has inserted `5`  inside `No of questions` field and clicked on plus button then five textarea are creating . Here i have also `minus` button and i need if user will click on the minus button the very last text area will delete and accordingly the `No of questions` field  will change similarly if the `No of questions` field value is changing accordingly it should create the text area dynamically.Please help me.

Comment: Adding a comment. If this works I will add as answer
$("#container").children().pop();

This will create an array of the children in #container. pop() will remove the last entry in the array.

Comment: @Gezzasa : Ok,Let me to implement this. I will inform u.

Comment: @Gezzasa : i added `$('#container').pop();`inside delete function but it is throwing me this `feedback.php:467 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pop is not a function` error.

Comment: There is more to this than I originally thought. Don't use duplicate ID's on your text area's. How about adding a minus button on each of the textareas (User might not want to remove the last one) and use the function $(this).remove();. If you get no other answers, this might be useful. Sorry for the time waster. For the textarea ID's, you've got the variable 'i' already from the for loop. Append that to the current ID and you won't have duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your deleteQuestionField() function can be something simple like this:

```
function deleteQuestionField() {
    $('#container textarea:last-child').remove();
}
```

Or you can use **.last()**, if you don't like the css's **:last-child** selector.

If you want to update the **No of questions** field, try this:

```
function deleteQuestionField() {
    var textareas = $('#container textarea');

  if (textareas.length !== 0) {
    textareas.last().remove();

    $('#ques').val(textareas.length - 1);
  }
}
```

Here's a working example.

```js
window.addQuestionField = function () {
    var get =$("#ques").val();
    if(get==null || get==''){
        alert('Please add no of questions');
    }else{
        var counter = 0;
        if (counter > 0){
            return;
        }else{
             counter++;
             for(var i=1;i<=get;i++){
                 $('#container').append(' <textarea class="form-control" name="questions'+ i +'" id="questions" placeholder="Questions"  style="background:#FFFFFF;" rows="2"></textarea>');
             }
        }
    }
}

window.deleteQuestionField = function () {
 var textareas = $('#container textarea');
  
  if (textareas.length !== 0) {
    textareas.last().remove();

    $('#ques').val(textareas.length - 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ques" value="">
<input type="submit" onClick="addQuestionField();" value="Add">
<input type="submit" onClick="deleteQuestionField();" value="Remove">

<div id="container">
  
</div>
```